# Ajax/jQuery show/hide .element on hover(): referring the hovered wrapper?

Tags: jquery, ajax, hover, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

This is one of my first try in jQuery/ajax, and i have a jam.

Here is my HTML code...

```
<div id="level_1_description" class="level_description wrapper">
    <h2><a href="#">Food</a></h2>
    <strong>..to have a good taste</strong>
    <p class="description"><span class="text">You want to eat healthy food.</span></p>
</div>
```

...and the script for animated hover action: show/hide the *.description* element in the *.level_description* container.

```
<script>
$('.level_description').hover(function(){
    $('.description').animate({height:$('.text').height()},100);
  },
  function () {
    $('.description').animate({height:1},100);
  }
);

</script>
```

working fine, but i have no idea how can i separate from the second wrapper (#level_2_description), witch has the same element (.level_description, .description)

i want to use something like this? :

```
...
$(this.'.description').animate({
  height:$(this.'.text').height()
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the elements based on the currently hovered element with the class leve_description. You can use jquery [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find elements within a parent element.

```
$('.level_description').hover(function(){
    var $levelDescription = $(this);

    $levelDescription.find('.description').animate({height:$levelDescription.find('.text').height()}, 100);
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.description').animate({height:1}, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for using context in the selector, and use a ternary to toggle such a simple animation :

```
$('.level_description').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.description', this).animate({
        height: e.type=='mouseenter' ? $('.text', this).height() : 1
    },100);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp9DA/)